# Accessing the Scenario Title and Example in a Cucumber After hook

Tags: ruby, cucumber, calabash-android

How can I get the current `Example` out of a Ruby cucumber test in an `After` hook?

I can get the title with the code below. My `Scenario` has several `Examples` with it. Can I access the current `Example` being tested?

**Feature file**

```
Scenario Outline: Successful login with primary accounts
  Given I start on the login page
  When I log into Overview page with "<acct>"
  Then I am on the Overview page   

Examples:
| acct          |
| account1      | 
| account2      |
```

**After hook**

```
After do |scenario|
  scenario.scenario_outline.title   # will give me the title
```

How to I get the current `Example`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it.

```
  scenario_title = scenario.respond_to?(:scenario_outline) ? scenario.scenario_outline.title : ''
  scenario_title_example = scenario.respond_to?(:name) ? scenario.name : ''
  scenario_full_title = scenario_title + scenario_title_example
```